# Obfuscation in Ext Js 4.2 with Sencha CMD 3

Tags: extjs4.2

I just installed all the required tools for the new Sencha Cmd(Ruby, Compass, Ext Js 4.2 SDK) everything works fine, but I don't know how to obtain the unique obfuscated file from the .js sources in my Ext Js application.
Any help, please? Thanks in advance.

I tried the "sencha app build" command from all the folders in my application path, always get the "Please ensure this command was executed from a valid application directory. Unable to locate 'app.dir' config property from 'sencha.cfg'

After more reading about the subject I think before the "sencha app build" command to work I need to generate the bootstrap.js file manually because my application wasn't generated using the framework, but I'm stuck here also. Anyone ever did that? Please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to get things work if your have legacy project (when project structure is not generated by sencha cmd tool) is to generate empty project and the move all necessary files/folders in to your existing project and try to adjust all configurations. You will need to move:

- .sencha folder
- folder with extjs development classes
- bootstrap.js, bootsrap.css, build.xml
- modify you start page correspondingly (index.html, index.jsp, or whatever)
- create application.js to start your application

bootstrap files are always generated automatically. To generate it normally you have to use *sencha app refresh* command.

Basically the most important changes have to be made in **.sencha** folder. Most of the config files in this folder have a lot of comments so this is not a problem to understand what to change. Also it's good idea to refer official doc page: [Sencha CMD](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/3.1.2/#!/guide)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've already done it using  Sencha Tools, because I couldn't get it work the way you suggested it. I spoke with a guy from the Sencha Team and he suggested the same approach as you did, but my application it's to customized.